# How to set colorbar labels

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colorbar

I have some points in a 'jet' colormap. The points have a coefficient that can go from 0 to 1, but usually they dont cover all the range, e.g 0.75-0.9.

When I plot those points I colour them so 0.75 is the lesser colour in the colormap and 0.9 is the maximum color in the colormap, so all the colormap is shown. What I want to do is show that in the colorbar also. When I plot the colorbar the labels on it go to 64, but I want them from 0.75 to 0.9. How can I do that?

**EDIT**
I don't think the code itself helps a lot but here it goes, just in case. In the `colors` variable I convert the `ZNCC` to the range of the colormap.

**EDIT2**

I found the reason why `caxis` is not working for me. Here is the code:

```
%this is why it doesnt work
im=imread('someimageyouwanttotest_inRGB.png')
imshow(im)


points=[1, 2;1 , 2 ;0.3,0.7]
ZNCC=points(3,:)
cmap=colormap('jet');
colors=cmap(round(  ((1-min(ZNCC))+ZNCC-1).*(size(cmap,1)-1)/max((1-min(ZNCC))+ZNCC-1))+1,:  );
hold on
for i=1:length(ZNCC)

    plot(points(1,i),points(2,i),'.','Color',colors(i,:));  

end
colorbar()
hold off
```

Comment: Have you tried caxis: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html ?

Comment: @Dan humm... what i understand is that caxis sets the range od the colors to the desired one. I already have that. The colors are plotted as Iwant, but in the colorbar the numbers in the colors do not correspond to the numbers of my data, they are from 0-64 instead of from min to max

Comment: How did you set the range? Maybe you should try using `caxis` instead because I think that will sort out the colorbar range at the same time. I had a look at a past script of mine that used `caxis` and the colorbar range matches what I specified with `caxis`.

Comment: @Dan I could achieve nothing with caxis. It just ploted everything in that range, but normalized. So all my points were blue.

Comment: I can't comment much more without seeing code. But if the answer below is correct then I don't think I understood your question anyway.

Comment: @OlegKomarov Not anymore!

Comment: @OlegKomarov There it is a sample input, but that was not hard. :D

Comment: `caxis([min(ZNCC) max(ZNCC)]); colorbar();` should do the trick

Comment: @Tobold it is weird.... With the posted data It works, but it doesnt work with my huge amount of data. Ill edit the quiestion with more info, but I am confused

Comment: @Dan I found why caxis is not working for me. I plot the points over an image. Just changing that makes caxis not set the colorbar. Any clues?

Comment: @Tobold It doesnt work. I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is your code displays all your colours correctly then rather just set up the colour bar first on no image:

```
points=[1, 2;1 , 2 ;0.3,0.7]
ZNCC=points(3,:)

cmap=colormap('jet');
caxis([min(ZNCC) max(ZNCC)]); 
colorbar();

hold on

%this is why it doesnt work
im=imread('someimageyouwanttotest_inRGB.png')
imshow(im)

colors=cmap(round(  ((1-min(ZNCC))+ZNCC-1).*(size(cmap,1)-1)/max((1-min(ZNCC))+ZNCC-1))+1,:  );

for i=1:length(ZNCC)

    plot(points(1,i),points(2,i),'.','Color',colors(i,:));  

end

hold off
```

I can't test it as I don't have `imshow` :/

Comment: Nope, there is no change in the result from your code to mine :(

Comment: If you step through the code, is the colorbar correct before you call imshow? Also try leaving the last call to colorbar at the end out?

Comment: It works if you take out the last colourbar() of the code you posted. I just don't knwo why. It is the only order of code to make this works it seems. Ill edit your answer and accept it.

Comment: I guess then that calling imshow resets the colorbar and then recalling colorbar at the end calls this new reset colorbar :/ glad the order changing worked though!

Answer (score 1):

If `caxis` is not working for you, you could store the return from `colorbar` - it is a handle to the colorbar object. Then you can set its properties, like `'YTick'` and `'YLim'`. The full list of properties you can set is the same as the [Axes Properties](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html) (because the colorbar is just an axes object, after all).

Here is an example:

```
% Generate some random data
z = rand(10);
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:size(z, 1));

% Plot colour map
pcolor(x, y, z);
shading interp; % Comment out to disable colour interpolation
colormap jet;

% Setup colorbar
c = colorbar();
set(c, 'YTick', [0.75 0.875 1]); % In this example, just use three ticks for illustation
ylim(c, [0.75 1]);
```

It is only necessary to do this once, after you've finished plotting.

**Edit:** If you need the limits and ticks automatically from the data, then you can do something like

```
% Find the limits
lims = [min(z(:)) max(z(:))]; 

% Function for rounding to specified decimal places
dprnd = @(x, dps)round(x*(10.^dps))./(10.^dps);

% Generate ticks
nTicks = 5; 
nDps = 2;
ticks = dprnd(linspace(lims(1), lims(2), nTicks), nDps);

set(c, 'YTick', ticks);
```

Comment: Sorry but same. This is working perfectly without the `imshow()`, but once shown an image the labels of the colorbar() are not there.