# Correctly change the labels of my colorbar?

Tags: matlab, colors, matlab-figure

I have data which is logarithmic. This is how I plot it:

```
contourf(x, y, log10(my_data));colorbar;
```

Now, the image looks well - colors are scaled accordingly to the value of each point, so my image is colorful. However, the values displayed next to my colorbar are wrong- they miss the base (i.e. I have *3* instead of *10^3*). So I tried using *caxis* as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010757/how-to-set-colorbar-labels):

```
cmin = min(my_data(:));
cmax = max(my_data(:));
C = contourf(x, y, log10(my_data));colorbar;caxis([cmin cmax]);
```

It helped a little bit: the values displayed by the colorbar are correct. However:

1. My image is now of one color as if I plotted my_data instead of log10(my_data). According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html), this is an intended effect. **How do I get rid of it**?
2. The values on the colorbar are displayed as 100, 200, 400, itd. H**ow can I change it to the scientific notation?**

**Edit**: Souver's idea works. However, my original ticks aren't just nice powers of *10*. So the new ticks were the following: *10^-1*, *10^-0.5*, *10^0*, *10^0.5*, *10^1*, etc.  But I don't want ticks such as *10^-0.5*, *10^0.5*, etc. So I have a new (shorter) list of the ticks and the labels that I want:

```
set(cbar, 'TickLabels', new_labels)
```

Now my labels look like that: *10^-1*, *10^-0*, *10^1*, *10^2*, *10^-1*, *10^-0*, *10^1*, *10^2*, etc.

How should I deal with that?

Comment: Use `labels = arrayfun(@(x)['10^{', num2str(x),'}'], ticks, 'uniformoutput', false);` Notice the `{...}` added...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to modify the [`TickLabels`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar-properties.html#property_ticklabels) property to create a custom label for each tick mark. You can retrieve the current [`Tick`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar-properties.html#property_ticks) locations and then create a label for each one.

```
cbar = colorbar;

% Get the current location of the tick marks
ticks = get(cbar, 'ticks');

% Now create a label for each tick mark (you can modify these however you want)
labels = arrayfun(@(x)['10^', num2str(x)], ticks, 'uniformoutput', false);

% Assign the labels to the colorbar
set(cbar, 'TickLabels', labels)
```

**Update**

You can also manually specify the tick locations yourself prior to running the above code.

```
ticks = [0 10 100 1000];
set(cbar, 'ticks');
```

Comment: thanks. But what should I do when I want to have less ticks than in my original plot? I used the code from your answer and got ticks such as *10^1.5*. This is not surprising since my original ticks aren't strictly powers of *10*. I tried filtering out the ticks I don't want. But matlab tries to assign a label to each tick. So now the ticks repeat themselvs. How should I deal with it?

Comment: you can achieve manual labels by `set(cbar, 'Ticks', yourticks, 'TickLabels', yourlabels`. `yourticks` has to be vector containing the ticks while `yourlabels` has to be a cell array containing the according strings. In addition you may take a look at the [matlab documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html#bt56gkg)